# Comparative bar graph using addplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart

I am trying to sketch the following graph.
[image: Desired output]

Using addplot, I have managed to draw the following.
[image: Current output]

What I am having trouble with is drawing two bars for one agegroup.
This must involve reducing the height of each bar, but unsure how to achieve this.Could anyone please help me?

Thank you!

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.05in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newtheorem{theorem}{THEOREM}
\newtheorem{proof}{PROOF}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{bigints}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{color,xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs,array}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{polynom}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\newenvironment{tightcenter}{
\setlength\topsep{0pt}
\setlength\parskip{0pt}
\begin{center}}{\end{center}}
\begin{document}
\text{}\\\\
\\
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis line style={thick,-},
name=like,
scale only axis,
xbar,
xmin=0,
xmax=7.2,
ymin=0.1,
ymax=1.3,
%
grid style={line width=.1pt, draw=black!60},
grid=major,
ymajorgrids=false,
tick label style={font=\Large},
width=8.2cm,
height=4.5cm,
%
xtick={1,2,3,4,5,6,7},
ytick={0.3,0.6,0.9,1.2},
y tick label style={text width=3cm,align=center},
%
axis x line=left,
axis y line=none,
clip=false
]
\addplot[fill=gray,minimum height = 0.06cm] coordinates {
(6.78,0.3)
(6.54,0.6)
(5.92,0.9)
(5.2,1.2)
};
%
\node[xshift=-1.0cm,align=center] at (axis cs:0,1.2) {\Large 15 - 19};
\node[xshift=-1.0cm,align=center] at (axis cs:0,0.9) {\Large 10 - 14};
\node[xshift=-1.0cm,align=center] at (axis cs:0,0.6) {\Large 5 - 9};
\node[xshift=-1.0cm,align=center] at (axis cs:0,0.3) {\Large 0 - 4};
%
\node[below] at (axis cs:-2,0.08) {\Large 0};
\node[below] at (axis cs:+0,0.08) {\Large 0};
%
\end{axis}
\begin{axis}[ 
at={(like.north west)},anchor=north east, xshift=-2.0cm,
scale only axis,
axis line style=thick,
xbar,
xmin=0,
xmax=7.2,
ymin=0.1,
ymax=1.3,
%
grid style={line width=.1pt, draw=black!60},
grid=major,
ymajorgrids=false,
%
tick label style={font=\Large},
xtick={1,2,3,4,5,6,7},
ytick={0.3,0.6,0.9,1.2},
yticklabels={},
width=8.2cm,
height=4.5cm,
x dir=reverse,
axis x line=left,
axis y line=none,
]
\addplot[fill=black] coordinates {
(6.8,0.3)
(6.1,0.6)
(5.2,0.9)
(4.25,1.2)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Doesn't it work to just add a second \addplot using the same y-values?

Comment: That actually worked, thank you! Any idea on how to reduce the height of each bar? It looks like the gaps between agegroups look so tiny, making the graph hard to read

Comment: Actually, found the solution. Set "bar width=x cm" in addplot to control bar height! :)

Answer (score 1):

To control bar height,

```
\addplot[fill=blue,bar width=0.15cm] coordinates {
```